# Finding occurrences of substrings within pandas dataframe -- Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a list of 'words' I want to count below

```
word_list = ['one','two','three']
```

And I have a column within pandas dataframe with text below.

```
TEXT
-----
"Perhaps she'll be the one for me."
"Is it two or one?"
"Mayhaps it be three afterall..."
"Three times and it's a charm."
"One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish."
"There's only one cat in the hat."
"One does not simply code into pandas."
"Two nights later..."
"Quoth the Raven... nevermore."
```

The desired output that I would like is the following below, where I want to count the number of times the substrings defined in word_list appear in the strings of each row in the dataframe.

```
Word | Count
one        5     
two        3     
three      2
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
In [52]: pd.Series({w: df.TEXT.str.contains(w, case=False).sum() for w in word_list})
Out[52]:
one      5
three    2
two      3
dtype: int64
```

Or, to count multiple instances in each row

```
In [53]: pd.Series({w: df.TEXT.str.count(w, flags=re.IGNORECASE).sum() for w in word_list})
Out[53]:
one      5
three    2
two      3
dtype: int64
```

Use `sort_values`

```
In [55]: s = pd.Series({w: df.TEXT.str.count(w, flags=re.IGNORECASE).sum() for w in word_list})

In [56]: s.sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[56]:
one      5
two      3
three    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked wonderfully. By chance, is there also a way to organize the list from most frequent to least frequent?

Comment: @Leggerless Yes, you call sort_values.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with vanilla python, first join the string:

```
In [11]: long_string = "".join(df[0]).lower()

In [12]: long_string[:50]  # all the words glued up
Out[12]: "perhaps she'll be the one for me.is it two or one?"

In [13]: for w in word_list:
     ...:     print(w, long_string.count(w))
     ...:
one 5
two 3
three 2
```

If you want to return a Series, you could use a dict comprehension:

```
In [14]: pd.Series({w: long_string.count(w) for w in word_list})
Out[14]:
one      5
three    2
two      3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @SunnysinhSolanki ah yes, depends what is column name of your strings, I guess should be `" ".join(df["TEXT"]).lower()`

Comment: I think this line should happen like this
long_string = " ".join(df[0]).lower() ## Added space in join
Because it might cause issue if we get list like below:
['text on','ending with'] == 'text onending with'
This will match 'one' which it should not.

Comment: @SunnysinhSolanki yes, good spot! I guess we could also add "\x00" if we wanted to be clever (assuming you're not matching strings with null.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what is n? It depends on how many substrings you have (if few this will be faster, I guess it's O(n*m) for n is long_string length and m is number of substrings)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ which is to say, if m is large yours will be faster (but if m is small this might beat you).

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extractall` + `value_counts`:

```
df

                                         text
0         "Perhaps she'll be the one for me."
1                         "Is it two or one?"
2           "Mayhaps it be three afterall..."
3             "Three times and it's a charm."
4  "One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish."
5          "There's only one cat in the hat."
6     "One does not simply code into pandas."
7                       "Two nights later..."
8             "Quoth the Raven... nevermore."

rgx = '({})'.format('|'.join(word_list))
df['text'].str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()

one      5
two      3
three    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

---

**Details**

```
rgx
'(one|two|three)'

df.text.str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0]

   match
0  0          one
1  0          two
   1          one
2  0        three
3  0        three
4  0          one
   1          two
5  0          one
6  0          one
7  0          two
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**Performance**

#### Small

```
# Zero's code 
%%timeit 
pd.Series({w: df.text.str.count(w, flags=re.IGNORECASE).sum() for w in word_list}).sort_values(ascending=False)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop
```

```
# Andy's code
%%timeit
long_string = "".join(df.iloc[:, 0]).lower()
for w in word_list:
     long_string.count(w)

10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop
```

```
%%timeit
df['text'].str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.53 ms per loop
```

#### Large

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)
```

```
%%timeit 
pd.Series({w: df.text.str.count(w, flags=re.IGNORECASE).sum() for w in word_list}).sort_values(ascending=False)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.34 s per loop
```

```
%%timeit
long_string = "".join(df.iloc[:, 0]).lower()
for w in word_list:
    long_string.count(w)

10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop
```

```
%%timeit 
df['text'].str.lower().str.extractall(rgx).iloc[:, 0].value_counts()
1 loop, best of 3: 4.12 s per loop
```

Comment: I am intrigues by which of these will be the most performant, I claim it's either this one or mine. Unclear how much indirection python adds here (I don't think the DataFrame helps any). Is the `.iloc[:, 0]` since it returns a DataFrame rather than a Series?

Comment: @AndyHayden Yes. `extractall` returns a Multiindex with one column, that's why I just grab the first column and call value_counts. I'll add some timings for this data :-)

Comment: @AndyHayden The winner is your answer by miles. Wow!

Comment: @AndyHayden Though I haven't increased `w`. That'd make a huge different I'd assume.

Comment: yup! make it 50 odd runs through and it's not looking so good, basically the playoff is O(n * m), my answer basically relies of python string manipulation (which is very fast... if we only do it a few times) as no indirection/basically just C. I suspect Zero's answer will also be hit with m similarly to mine.